# Check if a cv::Point is inside a cv::Mat

Tags: c++, opencv

Does anyone know if Opencv provide a function to check if a cv::Point is inside a cv::Mat ?

Basically I am doing:

```
int x = (current.x - offset);
int y = current.y;
if (x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x < mat.cols &&  y < mat.rows) && ((int)mat.at<uchar>(y, x) == 0)){
        return cv::Point(x, y);
    }
}
```

I would like to know if there is something faster ? Or if this was bad to do this ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can construct a `cv::Rect` of the size as the `cv::Mat` and use its `contains()` method:

```
cv::Rect rect(cv::Point(), mat.size());
cv::Point p(x, y);

if (rect.contains(p) && mat.at<uchar>(y, x) == 0)
{
  return p;
}
```

Alternatively, you can catch exceptions in `at()` if indices are out of bounds:

**UPD:** As properly mentioned by @Antonio in the comments, the following works only in debug mode, since "[For the sake of higher performance, the index range checks are only performed in the Debug configuration](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-at)", which is kind of surprising and is different from how [`std::vector::at()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) works.

```
try
{
  if (mat.at<uchar>(y, x) == 0)
  {
    return cv::Point(x, y);
  }
}
catch (cv::Exception& e)
{
}
```

However, be aware of the potential performance penalty caused by exceptions. You shouldn't use the latter approach if this statement is executed in a loop or just very often. Or in case it is normal rather than exceptional situation.

Comment: Like you said this is in a loop process, that's why I am searching best practices. Don't you think that creating cv::Rect is a bit heavy ?

Comment: I assumed you do several checks for the same image, thus a single rect should be created. If not, it might be slightly slower than your initial sample. If you want something more efficient than 4 simple inplace checks, more context is needed. Branch prediction and speculation done by CPU come into play in this case.

Comment: @Mikhail The method `at` throws out of range exceptions only when OpenCV is built in debug mode. "[For the sake of higher performance, the index range checks are only performed in the Debug configuration.](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-at)"

Comment: @Antonio Very useful comment, thank you! I've updated the answer.